# How can I sort the items in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I want my `ListView` to be sorted, How can I achieve this?` is there any method to do this job?

Java_Code:

```
String [] mplNames = retrieveMPLNames();
        List<String> sortedMPLNames = Arrays.asList(mplNames);
        Collections.sort(sortedMPLNames);
        mplNames = (String[]) sortedMPLNames.toArray();
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.savedlocationlist_layout, 
                R.id.savedLocationName, mplNames);
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

***Comments On the Code Above***

the list now has item starts with "0" as the first element and item starts with "y" as the last item, but in between, there is item named "Me" precedes item named "a coffee" in order, how could this happens in a sorted list,or i have done something wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String [] mplNames = {"one","two","three","four","six","eight"};
        List<String> sortedMPLNames = Arrays.asList(mplNames);
        Collections.sort(sortedMPLNames);
        mplNames = (String[]) sortedMPLNames.toArray();
       ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.mylist, 
                R.id.list_content, mplNames);
       mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

I have tried your code,its works fine.

remove `mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`from your code.

If you load the values dynamically, store the values in iterator and before store your values in list or else.At that time only you can use `mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
itr1=list12.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()&&itr1.hasNext())
    {
         mplnames.add(0, itr.next().toString());
         mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: if It's not fixed,post your retrieveMPLNames() method code

Comment: surprisingly, there is item named "Me" precedes itemed named "a coffee"?!

Comment: post your screen shot of Device

Comment: If you use hashmap it has two parameter key and value,"Me" may be a key value for your case

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: how did you fix that issue

Comment: I think it was happening because I have a search filter

Answer (score 0):

For any `listView` sorting first you have to sort the list or array which is passed `adapter` and then simply refresh the list i.e. `adapter_name.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Try this for converting the list to array

```
String[] mplNames = sortedMPLNames.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: would you please have a look at the updated code and comments

Comment: would you please tell me, should notify after or before setting the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

use `Collections.sort(your-list-name);`